# Why do two identical clists have different element counts?

Tags: pdftex, expl3, latex3

I create one global clist and assign `4, 300` as the two elements to it. `\clist_count:N` shows its 2 elements. If I copy this clist to a local list the contents of the new list are identical but `\clist_count:N` shows only 1 element. Why is that?

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_clear_new:N \g__timelist_median_clist

\clist_new:N \l__timelist_median_clist

\NewDocumentCommand{\setlist}{m}
{
    \clist_gset:Nn \g__timelist_median_clist { #1 }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\showlist}{}
{
    % set a comma separated list
    \clist_set:Nn \l__timelist_median_clist { \g__timelist_median_clist }
    
    g__timelist_median_clist:\ \clist_use:Nn \g__timelist_median_clist {,}\\
    count:\ \clist_count:N \g__timelist_median_clist\\
    
    l__timelist_median_clist:\ \clist_use:Nn \l__timelist_median_clist {,}\\
    count:\ \clist_count:N \l__timelist_median_clist\\
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \setlist{4,300}
    \showlist
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\clist_show:N\l__timelist_median_clist` to inspect your clist.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: What would that change? Then the list is no longer showing in my document... Supposedly it will show up in the terminal which I cannot find in TeXstudio... But again: what will that change or show?

Comment: you do not copy the list you make  new 1-item list

Comment: @mrCarnivore !!!!!! how do you manage to program _anything_ in tex without constant access to the log and terminal??????

Comment: sorry but if you really want to program you will have to learn to read the log and the terminal. expl3 has lots of helper commands that show you the current state of variables.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I do see the Log and the Warnings. The log is not that helpful most of the time though, especially when debugging functions... it never shows the line of the real problem.

Comment: it is absolutely vital, how do you think we debug your questions here? Your previous question showed multiple errors and I simply fixed one at a time as reported in the log even though I had no idea what the code was doing

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: You mean there really is a helpful log that helps? As I said: I see the Log and Warnings at the bottom of teXstudio but it never shows the real line of the problem it saw. I am fully aware that this seriously limits my ability to debug the code but thought unhelpful warnings and errors are just what you have to deal with in LaTeX.... How can I access the "real" and helpful terminal?

Comment: Also remember that what you see at the bottom of TeXStudio might be a filtered version of the log messages. It might be hiding relevant information. But as David says the log is vital to debugging problems.

Comment: You may even get false positives in the "simple" log the TeXStudio shows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add debugging messages:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_clear_new:N \g__timelist_median_clist

\clist_new:N \l__timelist_median_clist

\NewDocumentCommand{\setlist}{m}
{
    \clist_gset:Nn \g__timelist_median_clist { #1 }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\showlist}{}
{
    % set a comma separated list
    \clist_set:Nn \l__timelist_median_clist { \g__timelist_median_clist }
    
    g__timelist_median_clist:\ \clist_use:Nn \g__timelist_median_clist {,}\\
    count:\ \clist_count:N \g__timelist_median_clist\\
    
    l__timelist_median_clist:\ \clist_use:Nn \l__timelist_median_clist {,}\\
    count:\ \clist_count:N \l__timelist_median_clist\\

\clist_show:N\l__timelist_median_clist
\clist_show:N\g__timelist_median_clist
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \setlist{4,300}
    \showlist
\end{document}
```

you then see

```
The comma list \l__timelist_median_clist contains the items (without outer
braces):
>  {\g__timelist_median_clist }.
```

and

```
The comma list \g__timelist_median_clist contains the items (without outer
braces):
>  {4}
>  {300}.
```

as `\clist_set:Nn \l__timelist_median_clist { \g__timelist_median_clist }` does not copy the 2 element list, it makes a new 1-item list consisting of
the csname token for the global list.

you want `\clist_set_eq:NN`

Comment: I now see the contents you mention in the log. I was not aware that the log is the terminal. Also there seem to be two different settings of logs in teXstudio: one that only shows very few messages and another that shows the whole log file which you have to skim for the terminal messages. Thank you for helping me!

Comment: But where are the real line numbers of the problems? Or is that really hidden?

Comment: @mrCarnivore the log has more information than the terminal,   it is terminal output I showed there. texstudio's "summary" is worse than useless, I didn't show the line number above but in both cases it was logged as `l.33     \showlist` ie the message was triggered by `\showlist` on line 33